help me repeat the signal in python
help me repeat the signal in python.
The picture shows the signal after CWT analysis. It looks like a chirp 7-17K with some modulation.
Thank you.

I had to write a lot of code and try different approximation methods. You can see the code developments here.
https://github.com/karu2003/signal_hacking :)

Although you may have managed to solve the problem, your answer does not contain any information on the (possible) solution, except for a link to some repository. I strongly recommend you provide at least a minimal example (code and figures if possible would be great) of a solution and, at least briefly, describe it (what you did, how this solves the problem, etc.). These are mere recommendations, but I do believe they would greatly improve the quality of your answer.
